# Can Connect and Accept System Calls be used in the same program?

Tags: sockets, networking

I know if a client system is accepting connections, there will be a lot of overhead. But I am just curios if it is even possible? i.e. Can a program connect to a server and also open another socket to accept clients?

Comment: With the correct setup yes why not. That's basically how a proxy "server" works.

Comment: And that's the reason why the `select` call can poll a list of input and output sockets...

Answer (score 0):

It is common for a lot of more complex systems to be client and server.  I don't even know what you mean with a lot of overhead. I would do it using threads to separate the client and server part but even that is not necessary using one of the [poll/select network calls](https://www.ulduzsoft.com/2014/01/select-poll-epoll-practical-difference-for-system-architects/).

Answer (score -1):

> Can a program connect to a server and also open another socket to accept clients?

Yes, it (still ;-)) can!